# How can I update my page without having to logout/login

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

A user saves a recipe, and it's stored in mongoDB. I would like the saved recipe to be displayed automatically, but the user has to logout/login to see the saved recipe displayed. The same issue arises when the user deletes the recipe. I'm using a MERN stack and the user is logging in with react-google-login.

Comment: You'd need to share the relevant code so we can understand what's going on...

Comment: You can use `this.setState` within a component that will enable re-rendering of an element if it has been updated, in your case, the recipe. This is one of the benefits of using a library like react. [Here](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b) is a good article explaining how to use `setState`

Comment: Some important questions to think about -- how are you deciding what to render to the page? And then from there, after an update has been made, how are you deciding to update what you have rendered?

Comment: @waymobetta thank you, that waswhat i was missing.